# Changing Button Text Color

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I just need a simple button in clear color with black text inside. But the base button have white text. I need something to change the text color. [My curent app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZS0M.jpg)

```
<View style={styles.fastlog}>
  <Button style={styles.bouton}
    title= "Connexion avec Facebook"
    color= "#A2FFA1"/>
  <Button style={styles.bouton}
     title= "Connexion avec Google"
     color= "#A2FFA1"/>
</View>
```

this works, i have the green button, but i cant find for the text

Comment: what library is the Button coming from? also, please post styles.bouton and styles.fastlog

Comment: The button come from react-native library

fastlog:{
    width:245,
    alignSelf:'center',
    marginBottom: 50
  }
  bouton: {
    flex:1,
    paddingTop: 20,
    width:120,
    height:40,
  },

Comment: You should edit your tag from reactjs to react-native, since reactjs doesn't have Button

Comment: I imported everything from react-native

Answer (score 0):

Use Text inside Button and give color to text.

```
<Button
   style={styles.bouton}
   color= "#A2FFA1" 
>
 <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>Connexion avec Facebook</Text>
</Button
```

Reference: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/477

Comment: It doesn't work i've tried this numerous times, and i tried it again. it says "The title prop of a button must be a string"

Comment: Hmm. That's weird. I checked their documentation where I couldn't find an option to pass text color for a button. Have a look at this https://js.coach/react-native-button?search=button&collection=React+Native

Comment: I will try with the container style. But if i add an other library for buttons i can't use the first buttons right ?

Comment: What do you mean by first buttons ?

Comment: the buttons from th react-native library. Since we use import Button from.... i can't have both of them. But it's fine now it works with the other buttons i could change the font color !

Comment: If you want to use both Buttons on same page. 
Use `import CustomButton from 'react-native-button';` for external Button library and use `import { Button } from 'react-native'` for react native button. Then you can use it as `<CustomButton />` and `<Button />` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation i would suggest that you to use a third-party library or create a `customButtonComponent` as the Button component accessible from `react-native` do not have a lot of styling chances.

Note also that the prop `color` you are using changes the background color of the button only in `Android`, while it changes the text color in `iOS`.

Using a set of `TouchableOpacify` and `Text` you should be able to create a custom Button component stylable trough your own props and styles

Answer (score 0):

Button in react native has limited Styling property
You can use TouchableOpacity or TouchableHeighlight with Text Property Inside it,
So at the end you can use Styling property of View as Touchable Component as well as Text Property as well

```
    <TouchableOpacity style={{...yourStytles}} >
        <Text style={{...yourTextStyles}}></Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonSearch: {
    backgroundColor: "#F1F1F1",
    borderColor: "#D5D5D5",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 0,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
  buttonTitleSearch: {
    color: "#33353D",
  },
});

<Button
  navigation={this.props.navigation}
  title={
    this.state.searchPackageId
      ? "Package Id: " + this.state.searchPackageId
      : "Package Id: All"
  }
  // type="outline"
  buttonStyle={styles.buttonSearch}
  titleStyle={styles.buttonTitleSearch}
  onPress={() => {
    var navigation = this.props.navigation;
    console.log(this.state);
    navigation.navigate("PackageIdInput", {
      packageId: this.state.searchPackageId,
      updatePackageId: updatePackageId,
    });
  }}
/>
```

We can go to the index.d.ts to see the format of the component.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button
   style={styles.bouton}
   color= "#A2FFA1" 
   title="this is the title of your button"

>
 <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>Connexion avec Facebook</Text>
</Button>
```

You need to explicitly add `title`! This is if you have not solved it yet ,